# is it possible to run angularJS unit tests with angular-cli `ng test`?

Tags: angularjs, angular, unit-testing, ng-upgrade

I work on an AngularJS 1.6.X ES6 application.
I use Mocha and Sinon to write and run unit tests on it.

I started to hybrid/upgrade this application with ngUpgrade in order to write the new components in angular. So now, I got some angularJS modules and some angular modules.
I use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` with `babel-loader` and `ng-annotate-loader` to properly load the AngularJS modules.

I want to run the existing unit tests of the AngularJS modules at the same time as the unit tests of the new angular modules.
Ideally, I would also like to have a common code coverage report for AngularJS and angular modules.

Is it possible to do it with angular-cli `ng test`?
Which Karma configuration do you recommend?

Comment: Did you come up with any solution for this?

Comment: No... for the moment I use one karma conf for angular tests and an other for angularJS. So I got two code coverage report...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it with angular-cli ng test?

Yes, I think so. If you are running Angular 6 or higher, but I have not tried this myself.

Angular CLI introduced something called "builders" which allows you to replace the core CLI commands with your own functionality.

https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01

Basically, you can define your own `ng run <target>` targets that work similuar to `npm run <script>`. These *targets* are defined in your `angular.json` file and are coded in a JavaScript file. You can then map the built in target `ng test` to a custom target to replace the built it one.

The above article gives an example for replacing `ng test` with a custom tester.